# Nginx redirect url to secure domain

Tags: http, nginx, web, https

My webstie is hosted on aws EC2 instance and I have nginx 1.12.2 and Ec2 Operating system is centos, how do I redirect http://example.com and https://example.com to https://www.example.com .

Thanks

Comment: are you using aws route53 ???

Comment: no I am not using anything else only these much thing I am using.

Comment: no I am not using anything else only these much thing I am using. Godaddy I am using.

Comment: you just wanna show the www on an url or you wanna forward it to totally another domain ?

Comment: not only wanna show but really needs to redirect the above url I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You will need 3 server sections (and I'm almost sure you forgot to handle http://www.example.com case)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com; 
    location / {
             return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
           }
...

server {
    listen 443 ssl; 
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate ...
    location / {
             return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
           }
...

server {
    listen 443 ssl; 
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate ...
    location / {
             #your configuration here
           }
...
```